# nested grid in kendo asp.net mvc5 The Insert data binding setting is required by the insert command Kendo Grid Error anyone

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

The Insert data binding setting is required by the insert command. Please specify the Insert action or URL in the Databinding configuration.
this case does not need create method.

trying to call any method.
but also, not working how I can create nested Grid without create because I do not need create method my grid for show only.
I'm trying to create nested grid in asp.net mvc5 kendo grid in child grid I'm not needed to create method I need.
child grid to show Data only how I can handle this case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.